# i am not getting any errors , or exceptions , but the server consoles prints only null all the time whenever i execute the following piece of code

Tags: android, tcp, client-server

this is my clientcode

```
package com.example.simple_client1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private Socket client;
     private PrintWriter printwriter;
     private EditText textField;
     private Button button;
     private String messsage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); //reference to the text field
          button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   //reference to the send button

          //Button press event listener
          button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {

                messsage = textField.getText().toString(); //get the text message on the text field
                textField.setText("");      //Reset the text field to blank

                try {

                 client = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4444);  //connect to server
                 printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                 printwriter.write(messsage);  //write the message to output stream

                 printwriter.flush();
                 printwriter.close();
                 client.close();   //closing the connection

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
               }
              });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**my servercode**

package a_server;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class simple_server {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);  //Server socket
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
        }


        while (true) {
            try {
                 System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();//accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                System.out.print(message);
                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what went wrong ?

1. why its showing Null all the time at the server part ?
2. and at the server console side , it contains the previous null values even if i re-run the program !! how to flush it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Use a different thread to do all the server thing in your client side code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Use println() instead of write().
2. You're not checking the result of readLine() for null before you use it. You must do  that first, and if true, close the socket, and don't process the null as though it was input. It isn't.
3. When you get an exception, print *its* message. Don't just completely substitute one of your own. Otherwise debugging becomes just a guessing game.